# NamedCache sizeInBytes() method

Tags: java, caching, methods, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Does the NamedCache map actually has an implementation for sizeInBytes() method, i see these being referenced in the Kafka source code. However I'm unable to see any reference to this method in the Oracle documentation.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/internals/ThreadCache.java

Comment: What do you mean with Oracle documentation? `NamedCache` is also an internal kafka class: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/internals/NamedCache.java

Comment: @erwinboldwidt Sorry i got that confused with the following.. its an intellij idea thing i couldnt reach the definition . So i thought its the following http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/330/com/tangosol/net/NamedCache.html